# NextJS priority and unoptimized images not loading width and height properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

```
        <Image
          id={`img_${index}`}
          key={`img_${index}`}
          src={url}
          alt={url}
          unoptimized={true}
          priority={true}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit='contain'
          onLoadingComplete={() => {
            if (!loadedUrls.includes(url)) {
              setLoadedUrls((loadedUrls) => [...loadedUrls.filter(x => x !== url), url])
            }
          }}
        />
```

for some reason on desktop this works great. But on iOS sometimes I have to refresh the page for the image to show. I inspected with Inspector on my iPhone and the image had no width or proper height from the static source image file. Yet when I reloaded the page after it's inital download of the images it was correct. Why....

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should provide `width/height` unless its a statically imported file that next can analyze at build time.

Based on the code you provided, it looks like `src={url}` would evaluate to a image path and not a [static](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#local-images) image, i.e

`import profilePic from '../public/me.png`

See the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#width) note on width

> The width of the image, in pixels. Must be an integer without a unit.
> **Required**, except for statically imported images, or those with layout="fill".

If its the layout shifts you are concerned about you can also use
[aspect-ratio](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/)

Comment: _"Required, except for statically imported images, **or those with `layout="fill"`.**"_ - OP is using `layout="fill"` so the `Image` does not require width/height.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks , missed the `layout="fill'"` ! 

@colby-mchenry, please post a Minimum Reproducible example that can be tested.